# How do you dynamically load two different CSS file into a Flex application?

Tags: apache-flex, air, flash

i used  blue.css and also beige.css in flex .i have theme combobox for user changed theme dynamically so i stroed

[Bindable]
private var pickcss:Array=["blue.css","beige.css"];

private function css_initializeHandler(event:Event):void

```
    {
        pickcssComboBox.selectedIndex = pickcss.indexOf(0);
     }
```

private function css_changeHandler(event:Event):void
        {

//here how will i apply
         styleid= [ pickcssComboBox.selectedItem ];
        }

" mx:Label text="Theme"/>

"mx:ComboBox id="pickcssComboBox" dataProvider="{pickcss}"
    initialize="css_initializeHandler(event)"
    change="css_changeHandler(event)" width="110"/>"

i used   in style not have id so how can i do ? if u know plz explain

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, to load style sheets dynamically you need to compile them into separate .swf files. This can be done with mxmlc (or in Flex Builder by right-clicking on the css file and choosing "Compile CSS to SWF").
Then, to load the style-swf, you use the StyleManager

```
StyleManager.loadStyleDeclarations("blue.swf");
```

When you want to switch between styles, you'll also want to unload the previous style. So, assuming you put the name of css file in your combobox, in your css_changeHandler you'll do something like this:

```
StyleManager.unloadStyleDeclarations(styleid)
styleid = pickcssComboBox.selectedItem;
StyleManager.loadStyleDeclarations(styleid);
```

See [Loading style sheets at run time](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=styles_10.html) for more details.

Comment: Very very useful to me . thanks Wouter Coekaerts .how do i  set style id .i put name of css file in combobox like Blue theme and beige theme it showing properly . but how to switch